# Yii - Url Manager

Tags: php, url, yii

I want to change this url `_http:sitename/SsPartner/partner/id(string)` to `_http:sitename/partner/id(string)`

```
array{
'partner/<id:\w+>'=>'SsPartner/partner/<id:\w+>',
}
```

Is it Possible to change url like this, if so can you plz help me to achieve it.

Comment: Can you show us an example of real url, that you are checking and other that works by default?

Comment: am using in localhost, this is default url http://shopperspace.loc/sspartner/partner/CMP1002 and want to make it as http://shopperspace.loc/partner/CMP1002 and am getting id in my controller as public actionPartner($id){}.. is tat clear @alex

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: Opps!!! sorry its not working... am getting the same error...

Comment: shopperspace.loc/partner/CMP1002 - you'are checking this url? don't add '/' at the end of url, it may not works

Comment: am not adding any '/'. its not working...

Comment: check this 'ssPartner/partner' if controller named SsPartner and place rule at the first position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible

```
array{
    'partner/<id>'=>'sspartner/partner',
}
```

Comment: it works!!!. I changed this 'partner/<id:\w+>'=>'SsPartner/partner', from last to first in rules and it works. what causes it makes error when i put in last row??? can you explain??

Comment: I've another doubt @alex, how to achieve this.. 'partner/<id:\w+>/activities'=>'SsPartner/activities',

Comment: check this 'partner/<id:[\w\d]+>/activities'=>'ssPartner/activities'